# How to apply different style to different tags which has same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqgrid

can anyone please suggest me a way to style differently the 2 tags which has same class?

i have 2 tables

```
<table id="tab1" class=".ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hbox">
<table id="tab2" class=".ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hbox">
```

first table is the jqgrid which is on the page and second table tag has jqgrid which is inside the pop-up.now i wanted to style the top(labels/columns) rows of both the jqgrids differently.But whenever i apply apply style

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

it affects both the table tags.I want it to affect one first tag and i want to apply same style to other table tag but with extra properties.Please help thanks

Comment: You have to find something that differs in the second table from the first. Maybe a class on a parent element.

Comment: Have a look at the `:first-child` and `:nth-child()` selectors: http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Comment: Look with this example http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/Rz2Qt/

Comment: `i have 2 divs` but `<table id="tab1" class=".ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hbox">` seems table to me.

Comment: @SheikhHeera i made the change.thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Viking, can you add another class to the second table ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera i did and when tried using that class name to apply the style it didnt work.It still has the style like first table

Comment: Will they always be siblings? Can you post a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), that reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 1):

why not keep it simple, and just use the id's? Something like this:

```
.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-htable th div {
    /* applies to both tables */
}
#tab1 th div {
    /* applies only to table 1 */
}
#tab2 th div {
    /* applies only to table 2 */
}
```

Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Note that I also removed the space between the two class selectors (`.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-htable`), cause the way you wrote it `.ui-jqgrid-htable` would have to be a child of `.ui-jqgrid` before it would be applied, which is not the case in your HTML snippet

Comment: actually i did tried something like this but the reason it didnt work is bcoz it needs that ui-jqgrid-htable class for the jqgrid

Comment: Not familiar with jqgrid, but I don't see why you need the class names in your css. My suggestion applies to the HTML you provided, wich should be all the js looks at, it has no affairs with your stylesheet. But if you insist you could also use `#tab1.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-htable th div`and so on...

Answer (score 0):

If this is right for you

**HTML**

```
<table id="tab1" class="ui-jqgrid ui-jqgrid-htable">
<table id="tab2" class="ui-jqgrid ui-jqgrid-htable anotherClass">
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-htable th{
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    white-space: normal !important;
}

.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-htable.anotherClass th{
    /* some different styles*/
}
```

Also remove the dots from `class=".ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hbox"` class names. Check the demo, the second table has a different color font.

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5TyHu/5/)

Comment: when i change the class the style dont take effect for some reason

Comment: You have `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hbox`, remove the dots and make sure classes are same.

Comment: I think you have a cascading issue here, `.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-htable th` would take priority over `.anotherClass`. You would have to use something like `.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-htable.anotherClass th`as a selector for this to work on styles you have declared in both selectors.

Comment: I updated your demo (the html was wrong two) to demonstrate my point: http://jsfiddle.net/5TyHu/3/

Comment: np, cascading can be tricky sometimes. That is why I suggested to use the id's that already present, because they take priority in the cascading order, and it keeps your selectors much cleaner and shorter (and more performant!)

Answer (score 0):

```
#tab1{
  padding: 5px;
}
#tab2{
  padding: 2px;
}
```

I would have been using the `id`'s in the css.

Answer (score 0):

If we speak about jqGrid then it's important to understand that we specify initially `<table>` element like

```html
<table id="list"></table>
```

which will be **dynamically** converted to relatively complex structure with different divs and tables which looks about at following

[image]

Specifying of CSS with `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div {...}` you can change formatting of *column headers of the grid. If you have two grids like

```html
<table id="grid1"></table>
<table id="grid2"></table>
```

and want to specify CSS for column headers *only one grid* then you id of outer div "gbox" or "gview" which will be build based on the id of the `<table>` element. For example to apply CSS which you need to the grid `#grid1` only you can use

```css
#gview_grid1 .ui-jqgrid-labels th div {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

I used class `ui-jqgrid-labels` of `<tr>` instead of `ui-jqgrid-htable` to be sure that the CSS be applied on column headers only even if you [searching toolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching#calling_convention) in the grid.